# How to UTF-8 encode a character/string

Tags: c++, string, twitter, utf-8, character-encoding

I am using a Twitter API library to post a status to Twitter. Twitter requires that the post be UTF-8 encoded. The library contains a function that URL encodes a standard string, which works perfectly for all special characters such as !@#$%^&*() but is the incorrect encoding for accented characters (and other UTF-8).

For example, 'é' gets converted to '%E9' rather than '%C3%A9' (it pretty much only converts to a hexadecimal value). Is there a built-in function that could input something like 'é' and return something like '%C9%A9"?

edit: I am fairly new to UTF-8 in case what I am requesting makes no sense.

edit: if I have a

```
string foo = "bar é";
```

I would like to convert it to

```
"bar %C3%A9"
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you want to URL encode a string, not UTF-8 encode it.

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic: He needs both: "Twitter requires…UTF-8" and he is passing the value in a URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a wide character string, you can encode it in UTF8 with the standard [wcstombs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw%28VS.71%29.aspx) function. If you have it in some other encoding (e.g. Latin-1) you will have to decode it to a wide string first.

**Edit:** ... but wcstombs() depends on your locale settings, and it looks like [you can't select a UTF8 locale on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190190/wcstombs-character-encoding). (You don't say what OS you're using.)  [WideCharToMultiByte()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx) might be more useful on Windows, as you can specify the encoding in the call.

Comment: This function just seems to return the identical string as a c-style string, the "é" remains the same rather than being transformed into "%C3%A9".

Comment: No, I am :S -- wcstombs converts to the encoding for your configured locale, which looks like it's Latin-1 for me, so that's no good. If you're on Windows, you might like to try WideCharToMultiByte() instead. (Answer updated.)

Answer (score 6):

To understand what needs to be done, you have to first understand a bit of background.  Different encodings use different values for the "same" character.  Latin-1, for example, says "é" is a single byte with value E9 (hex), while UTF-8 says "é" is the two byte sequence C3 A9, and yet UTF-16 says that same character is the single double-byte value 00E9 – a single 16-bit value rather than two 8-bit values as in UTF-8.  (Unicode, which isn't an encoding, actually uses the same codepoint value, U+E9, as Latin-1.)

To convert from one encoding to another, you must first take the encoded value, decode it to a value independent of the source encoding (i.e. Unicode codepoint), then re-encode it in the target encoding.  If the target encoding doesn't support all of the source encoding's codepoints, then you'll either need to translate or otherwise handle this condition.

This re-encoding step requires knowing both the source and target encodings.

Your API function is *not* converting encodings; it appears to be URL-escaping an arbitrary byte string.  The authors of the function apparently assume you will have *already* converted to UTF-8.

In order to convert to UTF-8, you must know what encoding your system is using and be able to map to Unicode codepoints.  From there, the UTF-8 encoding is trivial.

Depending on your system, this may be as easy as converting the "native" character set (which has "é" as E9 for you, so probably Windows-1252, Latin-1, or something very similar) to wide characters (which is probably UTF-16 or UCS-2 if sizeof(wchar_t) is 2, or UTF-32 if sizeof(wchar_t) is 4) and then to UTF-8.  Wcstombs, as Martin answers, may be able to handle the second part of this conversion, but this is system-dependent.  However, I believe Latin-1 is a subset of Unicode, so conversion from this source encoding can skip the wide character step.  Windows-1252 is close to Latin-1, but replaces some control characters with printable characters.

Comment: I left it out above, but once you convert to UTF-8, you'll still call this API function to URL-escape the values.

Comment: Nice explanation. I feel like my understanding of encoding is enriched by this (never quite have been a fan of encoding). Thanks!