# Convert LPWSTR to string

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw

Function `CommandLineToArgvW` is giving me commandline arguments in `LPWSTR` type. I need these arguments in `string`.
Would someone please tell me how to convert `LPWSTR` to `string`?
I'm using mingw.

Comment: `std::wstring someParam = std::wstring(argv[0]);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use following API functions :

1. [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. [wcstombs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

And comparision of both methods [WideCharToMultiByte() vs. wcstombs()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620831/widechartomultibyte-vs-wcstombs)

Answer (score 33):

```
std::string MyString = CW2A (L"LPWSTR STRING");
```

You need to include `atlstr.h` for [`CW2A`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: The `CW2A` macro converts a wide character string to an ASCII string, so why are you sticking the result back into a `wstring`?

Comment: What do you #include for CW2A?

Comment: @ErikAronesty `atlstr.h`

Comment: This will not go well for japanese characters.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say yout LPWSTR variable is myVarL:

```
wstring ws( myVarL ); 
string myVarS = string( ws.begin(), ws.end() );
```

should make what you want

Comment: This will not properly deal with most of the possible characters in a wide string

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can convert LPWSTR to string:

```
// Assume you have initialized the lpwstr variable
std::wstring wString;
wString.append(&lpwstr[0]);
std::string convertedString(wString.begin(), wString.end());
```

Easy peasy

Comment: Please explain how this answer is any better than the one by Lambert Duran several years ago. And also explain how this "conversion" deals with characters outside the basic ASCII set.

Comment: Lambert's solution was easy. This one is easy peasy. Duh.